# Excel master sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have an Excel sheet which is used for bug-tracking. Each client has their own .xlsx and each application for that client has its own sheet within the .xlsx. So multiple Excel files with multiple sheets, all in the same format.

All sheets have the same headings and some columns have data validation and conditional formatting. Occasionally, however, the layout/headings or values allowed in data-validated cells, etc. must change and I have to go through each sheet and manually make the changes.

Is it possible to have a master sheet from which other sheets will inherit headings and heading styles with all cells under particular headings having data validation and conditional formatting?

(Before this is suggested, I used to simply put everything in one sheet and use filters to show a particular client/application, but this became impractical when sharing and versioning the sheets with multiple people)

Comment: how does that help? Perhaps you could have explained the reason for your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is a template. You create the template and give that to your 'clients' to track bugs. If you make an update to the template and give it to the client, they can just copy/paste data into the new form.

In my opinion, you're going about this the wrong way. Excel is a spreadsheet programme, while it CAN be used as a 'list' of sorts, it is a poor choice for bug tracking. If you're stuck on Office applications, use an Access database or something that can actually give you a 'front end display' separate from the 'back end data'.  There are many free bug tracking software programmes on the internet. Set one of them up and just have your clients log a bug there.

Comment: I agree it's completely the wrong way, but unfortunately a requirement. We use Jira and ideally that would suffice but in-house requirements are, unfortunately, a thing.

Thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 0):

Using a template and then getting the clients to copy+paste the old data is one way, but its not exactly the safest method.

If you did want to distribute a new template to your users it would be a good idea to add some import functionality. So VBA handles copying the old data across.

If you (personally) could do the changes to the template manually, then you might also be able to create a workbook+macros to "patch" the source (or a copy of the source) data in-place.

With either approach you'd probably need to add something to the source workbook to keep track of what version they have and make sure they they import from and to the correct version to prevent unhappiness in the future.

Could you show an example of a change? before and after etc